# highchart axis label can't set at beginning of the label?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I continue having issues with highchart.

I am generating a chart with given data.

My x-axis labels needed to be customized, so I pass a set of arrays

```
xAxis: {    
    min: -3.5,
    //catagories: [xaxis],                
    //type: 'linear',
    tickInterval: 1,
    //showFirstLabel: true,
    //startOnTick: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {                    
            return xaxis[this.value];
        },
        //tickPositions: -3,
        rotation: -90,
    },    
},
```

I've looked around and tried many things, what am I doing wrong?
the label starts at 0, I need it to start at beginning of the graph

[image]

Comment: You set the minimal value to 3.5, is it necessary? Try to remove it in order to let highcharts automatically determine the minimal value.

Comment: @ReuvenChacha, no dies not need to, removing it doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: @formosanblackbear, could you provide me with your chart configuration or live example with data included? It's hard to deduce how it's configured and what exactly can cause the problem.

Comment: Seeing as `xaxis` is an array, it makes sense it starts at 0. You are calling the index of `xaxis` with `this.value`. An index of the array can never be below 0.

Comment: How are your x-axis labels customized? Is this based on live data, or are they fixed? At any rate, it sounds like you want to use categories. Seeing the live data, as @formosanblackbear suggested, would also be very helpful.

Comment: @Codeer you are right, so.. how do I over come my issue?

Comment: I assume your x-axis is starting at -3, so that means `xaxis[this.value+3]` should work (shift the index with 3)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @codeer,

```
xAxis: {    
    min: -3.5,
    //catagories: [xaxis],                
    //type: 'linear',
    tickInterval: 1,
    //showFirstLabel: true,
    //startOnTick: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {                    
            return xaxis[this.value+3];
        },
        //tickPositions: -3,
        rotation: -90,
    },    
},
```

the +3 does solve my issue, i did tried with -3, but never tried +3.. thank you!